# custom array printing in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, printf

I know gdb has several means of exploring data, some of them quite convenient. However, I cannot combine them to get that I need/want. I would like to `display` some custom string based on the first n values of a big array starting at <PT_arr>, and the last m values of the same array at a distance (in this case) 4096. Looking something like this:

```
table beginning:
0x804cfe0 <PT_arr>: 0x00100300  0x00200300  0x00300300  0x00400300

table end:
0x804cfe0 <PT_arr+4064>: 0x00500300 0x00600300  0x00700300  0x00800300
```

- `printf` let's me add custom text (like `table beginning`)
- the examine `x` gives me that nice alignment, let's me read many elements and group them by byte, words, etc; and shows addresses at the left (which is ideal for my case).
- `x` aligns the content of regions of memory in an easy to read manner with the size and unit parameters. (what I want)
- `display` is constantly printing. (what I want).

The issue with  `display` ([manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html#Data)), is that unlike examine `x` ([manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#Memory)) it doesn't have a **size** or **unit** parameter.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: If `display` is what you want, why don't you use it? Edit: I just read it again, so you also want to include the `table beginning` text? Yes, that's not possible.

Comment: Where/when do you want to specify `m` and the distance from the start of the array? You can get close to `display` behavior by putting any sequence of commands you like in a `hook-stop` user-defined command.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, that sounds interesting... by `m`, I guess you mean "the address to inspect". That is given by a label in the source code. The distance, on the other hand, is just a number that I setup before running gdb. The whole point here is to get the pretty and aligned printing of `x` after every execution stop (after reaching a breakpoint, after a `step`, after a `next`, etc.). Could you, please, elaborate on the `hook-stop` approach as an answer, so I can try and select it as the ans to the question? Thanks.

Comment: @ssbssa, adding the string is not that important. But `x` let's me see the data very well aligned. `display` and `print` let me print arrays, but they are ugly and slow to read (I mean, read by my eyes)

Comment: From the looks of it you're using `x/4 PT_arr`, doesn't `display/4wx PT_arr` show it the same way?

Comment: @ssbssa As you can see in the [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html#Data), `display`, unlike examine `x` ([manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#Memory)) doesn't have a **size** or **unit** parameter.

Comment: @onlycparra As you can see in the [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html), `display` DOES have a **unit** parameter.